# Sending keystroke to detached screen session

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, keystroke

I'm writing a script which spawns several detached screen sessions to run cross-talking software inside.
Each instance of the software has an interactive behaviour: several keystrokes can handle the "device" state (e.g 'r' resets the device state, 'q' cleanly kills the device, etc.).

I have verified that everything works fine with the spawning of the devices.

At the end of my script I would like to send 'q' keystroke to every session in order to stop the device in a proper way and, after that, to detach the screen session.

What I am experiencing is that either I send 'q' with the following code:

```
screen -S <session_name> -p 0 -X stuff "q"
```

Or I re-attach to the session and I press 'q' on the keyboard, the result is the same. The keystroke is parsed as a null character and the device starts hanging asking repeatedly for a proper option.

Even if the behaviour of the device if improper option is gotten is not well handled (seems like a infinite loop), I think I am missing something about the screen input parsing.

The question, then, is:

**How is one supposed to simulate a keystroke in a detached screen session?**

Thank you in advance

UPDATE: it seems to me that the issue is caused by "-dm" screen option. If I create a screen session, I run the command inside, I detach it and then reattach and press 'q' everything is fine.

Comment: sounds like your software fails here...

Comment: I am sure it isn't. If I run the same software inside a screen session by hand I get the correct behaviour.